# Problem with solution in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

$22$ couples (of distinct men and women) need to be seated in a bus with $22$ pairs of seats (a pair of seats will be called a bench) (in total there are $44$ seats). Every bench must have one man and one woman. $21$ couples had a fight before boarding, so each man declared he won't sit next to his wife. Only one couple (let's call them Amy and John) didn't fight so Amy and John can either sit together or not. How many possible combinations of seating are there?

My solution:
First case: If John and Amy sit together, then there are $44$ places where John can sit, and then there's only $1$ place where Amy can sit, and then there are $21$ couples left. The remaining men can sit in $21$ different benches, so $21!$ choices for the seating of men in the benches, and their wives don't want to sit next to them so the choice for the wives is $D(21)$ (where $D(n)$ is the number of derangements on $n$), but we can also switch the order in which every pair sits in the bench so we need to multiply by $2^{21}$. By the multiplication principle we get $44 \cdot 21! \cdot D(21) \cdot 2^{21} = 22! \cdot 2^{22} \cdot D(21)$.

Second case: If John and Amy don't sit together, then there are $44$ seats where John can sit, then there are $42$ seats where Amy can sit (because Amy can't sit next to John or in John's seat), then $21$ options for the remaining women that can sit next to John, and $21$ options for the remaining men that can sit next to Amy, so far our solution is $44\cdot 42 \cdot 21^2$. Now, there are $20$ benches left, so the remaining $20$ men have $20!$ options to sit in the benches, and in order to not sit next to their husbands the women can sit in $D(20)$ positions, and to account for the inner order we need to multiply by $2^{20}$. So we get $44 \cdot 42 \cdot 21^2 \cdot 20! \cdot D(20) \cdot 2^{20} = 22! \cdot 21^2 \cdot D(20) \cdot 2^{22}$.

By the addition principle (and by simplifying) we get the final answer $22! \cdot 2^{22} \cdot (21^{2}\cdot D(20) + D(21))$

However, the answer in the textbook is $22! \cdot 2^{22} \cdot (D(22) + D(21))$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It might be easier to check with $c=3$ couples and ignore the $c!2^c$ terms for which benches and which way round on each bench.  There are clear $3$ possibilities which is $D(c)+D(c-1)=D(3)+D(2)=2+1$ rather than $(c-1)^2 D(c-2)+D(c-1)=(3-1)^2 D(1) +D(2) = 4\cdot 0+1=1$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the second case. If John and Amy don't sit together, then they are like all the other couples. There are $22!$ choices for the seating of the men, and then each wife won't sit next to her husband so $D(22)$ choices for the wives. Finally we need to multiply by $2^{22}$ to account for the inner order. So we get $22! \cdot D(22) \cdot 2^{22}.$ If we add it to the first case we get the desired final answer.

Comment: Nowhere is it specified that each bench must be occupied by one man and one woman. You could, for instance fill 11 benches with the women and the others with the men in ${22 \choose 11} (11! )^2$ ways.

Comment: I forgot to specify that and so I edited the question